# XSLT Muenchian Grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

I'm trying to group with XSL 1.0 and whilst it is kinda working in the current configuration, I'm struggling to understand how / why duplicate dates are being ignored. I've put a sample of the XML file below and the grouping sections of the XSL.

```
<flights>
        <flDate>2016-10-13T00:00:00</flDate>
        <airFrom>Glasgow International </airFrom>
        <airTo>Philadelphia, PA - International </airTo>
        <flNumber>US769</flNumber>
        <depTime>1020</depTime>
        <arrTime>1300</arrTime>
    </flights>
    <flights>
        <flDate>2016-10-13T00:00:00</flDate>
        <airFrom>Philadelphia, PA - International </airFrom>
        <airTo>Tampa, FL </airTo>
        <flNumber>US785</flNumber>
        <depTime>1550</depTime>
        <arrTime>1830</arrTime>
    </flights>
    <flights>
        <flDate>2016-10-22T00:00:00</flDate>
        <airFrom>Tampa, FL </airFrom>
        <airTo>Philadelphia, PA - International </airTo>
        <flNumber>US757</flNumber>
        <depTime>1410</depTime>
        <arrTime>1642</arrTime>
    </flights>
```

and the XSL

```
<xsl:key name="flDate" match="/invoiceSummary/itinerary/flights" use="flDate"/>

<xsl:for-each select="itinerary">
    <xsl:for-each select="flights">
    <xsl:sort select="flDate" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template match="flights[count(.|key('flDate', flDate)[1])=1]">
   Do whatever.......
</xsl:template>
```

The current output is:

```
ITINERARY DETAILS

13/10/2016 GLASGOW INTERNATIONAL TO PHILADELPHIA, PA - INTERNATIONAL
           FLIGHT NUM: US769
           DEPARTS: 1020 ARRIVES: 1300
22/10/2016 TAMPA, FL TO PHILADELPHIA, PA - INTERNATIONAL 
           FLIGHT NUM: US757
           DEPARTS: 1410 ARRIVES: 1642
```

As you can see the second leg of the flights (both out and back) are being ignored. I've tried changing the =1 on the grouping code but no joy.

Basically I don't fully understand Muenchian grouping.

Hopefully someone can explain it in simple terms or point me in the right direction.

The output is to a pdf using FOP, which again in my understanding doesn't support XSLT 2.0

### EDIT

Just to clarify (hopefully). I am creating a travel Itinerary with the data being loaded into the XML from MySQL which is then getting formatted using FOP and XSL into a PDF.

I would like to group the 'legs' by date which is occurring. However some 'legs' (flights, cruises etc...) can occur on the same date which is being ignored.

I am just looking for a way to rectify that issue.

Expected output.

```
    13/10/2016 Glasgow to Philadelphia
    ............................
    13/10/2016 Philadelphia to Tampa
    ............................
    22/10/2016 Tampa to Philadelphia
```

Cheers.

EDIT AGAIN

Solved the issue. Moved the Dates to it parent element and made it an attribute.

```
    <flight flDate="2016-10-13T00:00:00">.......</flights>
```

Feel so stupid. :(

Comment: *'"Basically I don't fully understand Muenchian grouping."* - That's where you should start. Hundreds upon hundreds of answers have been written on this site alone that explain Muenchian grouping. Blog posts and documentation articles exist on the topic. Every level and detail has been covered. Please don't ask people to write yet another introduction just for you.

Comment: Maybe if you update your XML to include the data that you're showing in your output and also add what the desired output should be (in code would be best), someone might help getting muenchian grouping working in your specific case. Right now it's tough though because you don't give us enough to reproduce the current output. For example, your current output has information about HOTEL LOS JAMEOS, but that's no where in your input (which isn't even well formed XML).